# Mysql посчитать количество записей

Tags: mysql

У меня есть две таблицы `table1` и `table2`. В `table1` есть две колонки `id`, `name`. В `table2` две колонки `id`, `idtable1`. В колонке `idtable1` содержатся `id` из `table1`.

Задача: Мне нужно посчитать количество. Сколько например записей в `table2`, где колонка `idtable1` равна `id`(из `table1`), где колонка `name`(из `table1`) равна "Вася"

Также буду благодарен, если посоветуете какие нибудь учебники по `Mysql`.

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id=table2.idtable1 AND table1.name='Вася';`

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/tutorial.html

Answer (score 1):

Вот так:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 t1 
  INNER JOIN table2 t2 
    ON t1.id = t2.idtable1 && t1.name ='Вася';
```

[Книга](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920022343.do)

Comment: в mysql можно использовать `&&` вместе `and`?

Comment: @Denis, да. Я всегда пишу именно так.

Comment: Проверил, и правда работает.